# Trying to create a variable data level tableview structure

Tags: ios, storyboard, tableview

I have a tableviewcontroller embedded in a navigationcontroller which is part of a tabbarcontroller.

When the initial tableviewcontroller is shown, it lists items.  Some of these items may have subitems which may also have subitems, and some may not.  In other words, the levels deep each item has is variable.

I'm trying to have the tableview controller instantiate a new instance of itself when a user clicks on an item using this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];

   ProtocolViewController *newVC = (ProtocolViewController *)[mainStoryboard    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"ProtocolView"];

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES];
}
```

But, it keeps crashing when I press an item in the tableviewcontroller (initial) and highlighting the storyboard line.  What's going on?  Each level will have different data, which I think I can get figured out how to load different data by passing some sort of reference as to what data it should be showing, but right now, I'm just trying to get it to push a new instance of the same tableviewcontroller over and over.

any help is appreciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I guess it was just the pointer code to the storyboard that was jacked up because either of these ways of referencing the storyboard makes this work.

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary objectForKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"] bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

-or-

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = self.storyboard;
```

:)